# avisynth (or a like tool) for linux

Tags: linux, media, script, avisynth

Is there a way to run avisynth on linux?

OR

Is there a similar tool? That is, a way to write a script file that can be played in a video player and/or fed into an encoder, etc.

#### Update:

My distro is min (ubuntu based).

I tried to build from source and failed (it's complicated, I might try again sometime).

**Let me Clarify**

I don't want to get avisynth to run as much as I want to be able to montage videos with a text/script file.

The *real* question here: is there something else on linux that allows this?

For instance: is it possible to use `gstreamer` to montage videos through scripts? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since no one mentioned it yet:

There's VapourSynth, a cross-platform toolkit very similar to AviSynth, which uses Python as its scripting language.

http://www.vapoursynth.com/

Example syntax:

```
import vapoursynth as vs
core = vs.get_core()
video = core.ffms2.Source(source='Rule6.mkv')
video = core.std.Transpose(video)
video.set_output()
```

To play a script file in a player (mpv):

```
vspipe --y4m script.vpy - | mpv -
```

To encode the script output using ffmpeg:

```
vspipe --y4m script.vpy - | ffmpeg -i pipe: encoded.mkv
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like wine + [avs2yuv](http://akuvian.org/src/avisynth/avs2yuv/) is the way to go

Quoting from http://akuvian.org/src/avisynth/avs2yuv/:

> Sample usage:
>   `wine avs2yuv.exe foo.avs - | mencoder - -o hfyu.avi -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=ffvhuff:vstrict=-1:pred=2:context=1`

Answer (score 1):

These days (2024, note dates of other answers) you can use the [AviSynth+](https://avs-plus.net) frameserver, which is fork of AVISynth that is cross-platorm, 64-bit-capable, and actually maintained. It builds and runs on Linux, and is actually packaged on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to compile it, there is [Avisynth 3.0](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Favisynth3.unite-video.com%2F&ei=YPnIStf9GorSsQOAkOChBQ&usg=AFQjCNHwQA8nBR2y8X6TxdtMsx7au9cITg) - source is available & there's a Gentoo binary distro.

Comment: link for the binary distro?

Comment: http://avisynth3.unite-video.com/avisynth-3.0-bin.tar.gz

Comment: That link is broken (I believe it was an April fools joke when they posted it)

Comment: Hmm.  It was live the day I poseted it, but the parent page (http://avisynth3.unite-video.com/download.html) doesn't read like yoyur typical April fools joke...

Comment: Avisynth 3.0 never really got off the ground.. It was an attempt to bring AviSynth natively to *nix, but didn't quite make it... (it was not a simple port).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an AviSynth build from Windows that you really like, and building your own doesn't work for you, you could try it in [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).  You don't give your distribution but it's likely available (if not already installed).

Comment: When I install it under wine, how do I make use of it?

Comment: If you have wine configured right, you should be able to run the .exe from a commandline.

Answer (score 0):

`avs2yuv` is an AviSynth proxy for programs which are not AviSynth **aware**. However `avs2yuv` only handles the video stream; audio is ignored.

That means that the audio must be handled seperately.  This often voids some of the strong features of AviSynth.. eg. to manipulate a section of audio, or if you want to cut the stream. you will of course want to cut the audio too...

---

A `wine` combination of the following 2 apps, enables the handling both audio and video streams concurrently, as you would normally expect from AviSynth...

- **[avidemux2 (for Windows)](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/)** when installing, select plugin: *Avisynth Proxy*
- **[avsproxy_gui (for Windows)](http://code.google.com/p/mulder/)** by MuldeR. This is the counterpart of *Avisynth Proxy*

[image: avidemux2 and avsproxy to the rescue]

---

You can also feed AviSynth scripts via `wine` to **[VirtualDub (for Windows)](http://www.virtualdub.org/)**.
It too handles both audio and video streams (as expected).

[image: VirtualDub]